# Why i get an "type mismatch" error?

Tags: vba, int

I got this question,
I have this line `Dim i, j, x, y, Labels As Integer` , and when I want to use the **Labels** variable in this following way inside a cycle i get an error: `Labels = CInt(DBRange.Rows(i).Item(10).Value)` , consider DBRange as one database on a worksheet with 10 columns and 10 rows as example.
So why I'm getting an "type mismatch" error if the variable **i** is an integer, and the variable **Labels** also is an integer, and if I'm converting the cell value to an integer with **CINT** function?

Comment: Database on a worksheet ? What does `Msgbox DBRange.Rows(i).Item(10).Value` returns ? And `Dim i, j, x, y, Labels As Integer` declares only `Labels` as Integer type Rest all variables of type `Varaint` i.e they can hold any data type value. Use `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, Labels As Integer` to declare them all as of type Integer.

Comment: Note: `Dim i, j, x, y, Labels As Integer` creates only one Integer variable (`Labels`). The other variables are created as Variant. You must specify the data type for every variable individually in VB(A) declarations.

Comment: Most probably the expression inside the CInt() function doesn't return a value that's convertible to an integer type. Since the Item() property of the Range object can lead to cells outside the Range which it's called upon I'd suggest to place a breakpoint at the offending line and use Immediate Window to query both the .Address and .Value properties of  DBRange.Rows(i).Item(10)

Answer (score 0):

@tomalak is correct that `i`, `j`, `x`, and `y` are variants and not integers. Only `Label` is an integer, variants can be slow to process and should be avoided.

With modern computing power and volume of work, consider `integer` obsolete with `Long` taking its place:-

A `Integer` can hold a number between -32768 and 32767

A `Long` can hold a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647

If `DBRange.Rows(i).Item(10).Value` ever contained a value outside of an integer range or acted as non-numeric by containing non-numeric characters (i.e. a space), then an error will occur. If `following way inside a cycle` is building up values that end up outside of an integer range then the error will occur.

To confirm, it is not the variable accepting the `CInt()` value that is causing the error, it is the act of `CInt()` that is causing the error.

My first debugging step would be to declare your variables fully: -
    Dim i      As Integer
    Dim j      As Integer
    Dim x      As Integer
    Dim y      As Integer
    Dim Labels As Integer

The second debugging step would be to convert them all to `Long`.

Finally use F8, it will show you the variable and from that [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) can probably give you the answer to the issue in exactly and instantly, history on an error is the important part of finding the solution.

Comment: _"To confirm, it is not the variable accepting the CInt() value that is causing the error, it is the act of CInt() that is causing the error. "_ what do you mean?

Comment: @user3598756 The function `CInt()` will error if your pass it a string (i.e. 'Hello World!"), it will not resolve it to nothing or zero for example. So its not passing a converted value into the `Integer` variable that's failing, its the `CInt()` trying to convert it to an integer that failing.

Comment: Which is precisely what I wrote in my comment. But only comments irrelevant to the issue has een upvoted. ..